# Javascript: Select parent of an element and make it hidden

Tags: javascript, parent-child, parent

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">

  (I want to select this div and make it hidden)
  
  <div class="ad-pric-content">
    <div class="ad-pic-style" />
    <div class="ad-pric-detail">
      <div class="col-lg-12 no-padding prod-fancy-btn">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"
           class="btn btn-theme sb_add_cart"
           data-product-id="10496"
           data-product-qty="1">Sélectionnez le plan</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to select the first Div which has as child element the  balise with this specific data-product-id 10496.
I can't use Css because there are also 2 others div with the same classes.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add a nice recognizable class to that parent. Say `product`
- Use Attribute selector `[]` to find the desired element by `data-*`
- use `.closest()`
- If found - assign a class like `"is-hidden"` to `.product` using `Element.classList` and the `.add()` Method:

```js
const prID = "10496";
const EL_prID = document.querySelector(`[data-product-id="${prID}"]`);

if (EL_prID) {
  EL_prID.closest('.product').classList.add('is-hidden');
}
```

```css
.is-hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<div class="product col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
  (I want to select this div and make it hidden)
  <div class="ad-pric-content">
    <div class="ad-pic-style" />
    <div class="ad-pric-detail">
      <div class="col-lg-12 no-padding prod-fancy-btn">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"
           class="btn btn-theme sb_add_cart"
           data-product-id="10496"
           data-product-qty="1">Sélectionnez le plan</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you I understand your code but  as I am working on a wordpress I can't add class to the div element as you suggested. I tried to replace it by:   EL_prID.closest('.col-lg-4.col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-xs-12').classList.add('is-hidden'); but it is not working